# What is the best practice to reconnect websocket

Tags: java, android, websocket

What is the best practice to reconnect websocket when the network fall. because I close and open the connection and the websocket is not reusable. If I create a new websocket connection Then, the server is received two connections.

Note : i'm using **TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket** library .

**UPDATE :**

thanks to @TripeHound : If the connection has failed, it's should have failed at the server as well, so the server should just discard the original (knowing that the client will reconnect when next it needs to).

i did managed to do what @TripeHound sayed .

if there is better practice for reconnecting i'll let you know .

Comment: use background service to check whether you are connected are not... else reconnect

Comment: @MustanserIqbal please read the question well , if i did that and I create a new websocket connection Then, the server is received two connections.

Comment: If the connection has failed, it's should have failed at the server as well, so the server should just discard the original (knowing that the client will reconnect when next it needs to).

Comment: thanks @TripeHound i will try to do what you said , please consider to voteup my question idk why it goes down